# Handling Advertisements in Native app using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-ios, appium-android

I am automating Android Native Gaming App, our app renders ads from different ad networks. After submitting each game you may see static ad and video ad or you may not see an ad at all. If video ad is found it may vary from 30 secs to 1 min.
Important thing, when i use Appium inspector to spy various video ad screens shall be identified only by Class(android.webkit.WebView, android.widget.VideoView, android.widget.Button, android.view.View, android.widget.Image & android.widget.ImageView.). After Ad complete playing we need to click on device back button and play next game.
Can you suggest any good approach to automate this kind of app? Any sample code is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Option I:** you have is to ask your developers to create a version of the application without ads.

Advantages - No ads.

Disadvantages - You will not be testing the exact same code as you plan to release.

You can disable only fullscreen ad.

I think there is no best way to do this. Stable automate checks or checking the exact same code as you plan to release.

**Option II:** is to catch if the ad is visible, and press back button.

For example (example fo Android):

```
protected boolean checkAdvert(AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver, int timeout) {
    By adTree = By.xpath("//hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]");
    Map<String, Object> adParams = new HashMap<>();
    //trying to wait for the ad to come up and then click the Expense button
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.context("NATIVE_APP");           
    FluentWait<WebDriver> await = new FluentWait<WebDriver> (driver)
            .withTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    try {
        await.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(adTree)));
        // go BACK to eliminate the popup
        adParams.clear();
        adParams.put("keySequence", "BACK");
        driver.executeScript("mobile:presskey", adParams);
        System.out.println("Press the back button to get out of ad");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception t) {
        System.out.println("no ad showed up");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and use this in page object class:

```
public void addExp(String desc, String amount) {
    do {
        try  {
            driver.context("WEBVIEW");
            driver.findElement(expDesc).sendKeys(desc);
            driver.findElement(expAmnt).sendKeys(amount);
            adClick = false;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ne) {
            adClick = checkAdvert(driver, 1);
            if (!adClick) throw ne;
        }
    } while (adClick);
}
```

But you must remember that ads may be different, you can try to find a universal selector. But I think it will hard to cover all cases.

```
adTree = By.xpath("//hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]");
```